# Hey, how can I see why fallback intent occured for a user in my live skill?

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

Can I see what my user said in my Amazon Alexa skill that caused it to have a fallback intent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently unavailable.

There are several versions of this feature requested on their official Uservoice though. They could all use some more upvotes... :)

- [Provide full user utterance](https://alexa.uservoice.com/forums/906892-alexa-skills-developer-voice-and-vote/suggestions/34248751-provide-full-user-utterance)
- [Send raw query with request](https://alexa.uservoice.com/forums/906892-alexa-skills-developer-voice-and-vote/suggestions/33395767-send-raw-query-with-request)

And your's specifically...

- [fallback](https://alexa.uservoice.com/forums/906892-alexa-skills-developer-voice-and-vote/suggestions/37798834-fallback)